# Type is not assignable in Vue component, but it's correct

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a error with typings in vue typescript during build.

```
 Type '{ [x: string]: any; name: string; parents: ...[]; id: string; createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Directory[]'.
  Type '{ [x: string]: any; name: string; parents: ...[]; id: string; createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Directory'.

             :directories="directories"
```

There is my component which requires `Directory[]` as prop:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Directories',
  components: {
    DeleteDialog, EditDirectoryDialog, ContextMenu, DirectoryItem,
  },
  props: {
    directories: {
      type: Array as PropType<Directory[]>,
      required: true,
    },
}
```

I try to call this component from another like this:

```
<Directories :directories="directories" />
```

where data looks like that:

```
data() {
      directories: [] as Directory[],
    };
```

There is no error when I call component like this:

```
<Directories :directories="directories as Directory[]" />
```

Comment: Can you also add what `Directory` looks like?

Comment: Options api isn't ts-friendly in general and one of the reasons for composition api to appear. Here it's evident that `data` type is inferred the wrong way on the instance. It's unknown which Vue version you use. If it's 2 then it could be different in 3.